Elementor custom widget using toggle javascript
I have created an Elementor custom widget, a clone of the official Toggle widget with the same code of the original but different widget name.
The problem is that the official javascript handler that manages the open/close feature is not attached to my widget and it's not working (all tabs are always closed and don't open).
Can I use the Elementor built-in JS handler with my clone in some way?
Thanks
